# Injecting parameters into Beans, CDI bean VS JSF bean

Tags: java, jsf, cdi, code-injection

after some experimenting, I have been able to inject my GET-parameters into an `@ManagedBean` (thus, a JSF) bean using `@ManagedProperty` and some EL.

Now, except the approach from reading the parameter map from `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()`, I have not been able to inject my GET-parameters into an `@Named` (thus, a CDI-) bean.

And so, I have been reading about advantages and disadvantages of JSF beans and CDI beans.
In short, I am stuck with two questions:
1st. Will I experience any disadvantages in using JSF beans over CDI beans?
2nd. If so, is there a clean way to inject my GET-parameters into a CDI bean?

Comment: If glassfish, then use the newest.

Comment: I am in fact using Glassfish, working on 3.1.2. Are you suggesting to switch to Glassfish 4? How would this help me, is there a new feature regarding this situation?

Comment: No, but there was some changes at one point consolidating JSF and CDI managed beans.  You might be using an older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that I don't start a flamewar here, but it's certainly safe to say that CDI scopes and dependency-injection mechanisms cover far more ground than JSF scopes do. Generally speaking, you are better off with CDI scopes - but one could go into almost arbitrary details here.

Concerning you problem: [Seam Solder](http://www.seamframework.org/Seam3/SolderHome) brings - among many other things - http-parameter-injection. Check [this](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/3.1.0.Final/reference/en-US/html/injectablerefs.html#injectablerefs.request_param) out.

**Update:**
Should you be afraid of integrating Solder into your project (don't be!), take a look at the [relevant source-code](https://github.com/seam/solder/blob/develop/impl/src/main/java/org/jboss/solder/servlet/http/RequestParamProducer.java) which does the magic. You can easily copy it into your project - it's just that the developers behind Solder had a few more cornercases in their mind than you would probably come up with on the spot.

Comment: Personally, I am indeed pro-CDI as far as my knowledge covers it. But concerning your advice on the HTTP-parameters, I am not eager to use yet another framework for a single function that is already covered by standard Java in some way. I guess my question could be better formulated as "What is the best way to inject my HTTP-parameters into a CDI bean using basic JEE functionallity?"

Comment: I don't want to be picky, but Solder is _the_ _most_ _important_ single CDI extension, not another framework. This makes it a first-class citizen in all CDI projects I have knowledge of.

Comment: Ok, thanks Jan! I will read some articles about Solder and give it a try. Thank you for all your help and you've earned my upvote.